# How to validate email without button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, email

I have the below code where i am validating email on button click. I want that email validation should happen without button click. Means i want when i will be writing the email in the text box, it should get validated.

Below is my code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form >
  E-mail: <input type="email" id="myEmail" name="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Regards

Comment: Always have server-side validation too. Never rely on client side only.

Comment: Validating a Email adress with regex is a nightmare. Be careful how you use it. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Answer (score 0):

You should run the validation code whenever the input field's value changes (validation code: match the current content with the regular expression). With jquery it looks like this:

```
$("#email").on("keyup change paste cut", function() { 
   // validate here 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should attach an event to that input element and validate it with javasciprt.

Check this working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ox7ak2ck/)

```
var patt = new RegExp("[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$");

$('body').on('keyup change paste cut', '#myEmail', function() {

    var res = patt.test($(this).val()) === true  ? 'Correct Email' : 'You have entered some crap';
  $('.result').text(res)
});
```

Comment: Hey Arif.. when i key in hh@--------------------.com email address, its showing as correct email which shouldnt be. Can u please check.

Comment: I've updated the Fiddle. Check again.
It was working fine, but you should create regex yourself as you want

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript and jQuery library you can attach and handle multiple events in the form fields.

Also you should add the `novalidate` boolean attribute in your form to prevent form-data (input) validation on submit:

```js
$('#form').on('keyup change paste cut click', '#mySubmit, #myEmail', function(e) {
    var pattern = /^\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b$/i,
        emailVal = $('#myEmail').val(),
        emailErrorMsg = (!emailVal || !pattern.test(emailVal)) 
        ? 'Error validation message'
        : '';

    $('.email-error').text(emailErrorMsg);

    if (emailErrorMsg) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

```css
.error {color: red;}
.submit {margin-top: 10px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" novalidate>
    Email: <input type="email" id="myEmail" name="email">
    <div class="email-error error"></div>
    <input type="submit" id="mySubmit" class="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Native JS Solution

You can use `this.checkValidity()` in combination with `onblur`:

```
<form >
  E-mail: <input type="email" id="myEmail" onblur="this.style.borderColor= this.checkValidity() ? 'green' : 'red'" name="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

```html
<form >
      E-mail: <input type="email" id="myEmail" onblur="this.style.borderColor= this.checkValidity() ? 'green' : 'red'" name="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$">
      <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Or in combination with `onkeyup` it will show the message (a little bit annoying):

```
<form >
  E-mail: <input type="email" id="myEmail" onkeyup="this.checkValidity() || this.form.submit.click()" name="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$">
  <input name="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

```html
<form >
  E-mail: <input type="email" id="myEmail" onkeyup="this.checkValidity() || this.form.submit.click()" name="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$">
  <input name="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

As a variation if you want to minimize the firing of the validation function, you can give the input type="submit" an id and attach a mouseenter listener (plus a function to prevent the function click if invalid email):

```
$("#input-submit").mouseenter(function () {
    //validation function - but also prevents the button click if email invalid
});
```

I have used this before - our QA tester tried everything he could to click the button before the validation function fired but could not.

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery library email validation. Just using very simple codes. Conditionally validation.

HTML codes

```
<body>
    <form action="/hello" onchange="ValidateEmail()">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your email address..." id='input_id' required>
        <button id="myBtn" type="submit">Notify Me</button>
    </form>
    <p id="validation"></p>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
 </body>
```

JS codes

```
function ValidateEmail() {
    var x = document.getElementById('input_id').value
    var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= x.length || x==='') {
        document.getElementById("validation").innerHTML = "Please provide a valid email address";
        document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true;      
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("validation").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = false;  
    }
}
```